# iOS 10 Widget: I Want to create Widget for My App

Tags: iphone, ios10

I have app same as Apple Health Activity. I want to Add my App in "Add Widgets" list. But I don't have any clue How to do that?
Can anyone tell me the procedure to do that?

Comment: it will be better if you add more specific and detail question though as I think.

Comment: begin here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/widgets/